# Allure2 How to integrate it with Jira Xray

Tags: testing, jenkins, jira, allure, x-ray

I am trying to integrate Allure2 reports with Jira plugin called Xray. So far i managed to generate those reports on local machine and on Jenkins server in pipeline job with Allure plugin.

Also i see that there is an actual Allure plugin called xray-plugin on Allure Framework GitHub, however instructions how to use this plugin are not clear enough for me (for example, where one should put those Jira env variables?).

Can someone here explain in more clear manner how to integrate Allure2 with x-ray?